# Zend Framework 3 AJAX responding data

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, zend-framework3

I try to do async contact form validation in ZF3 by using ajax. 
Thats my ContactController

```
public function contactAction()
{
    $form = $this->form;
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $vm = new ViewModel(['form' => $this->form]);

    $form->setInputFilter(new ContactFormFilter());

    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost())
        return new ViewModel(['form' => $this->form]);

    $data = $request->getPost();

    $form->setData($data);

        if (!$form->isValid())
        {
            $vm->setTerminal(true);
             return $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($form->getMessages()));
        }

}
```

and below is contact.phtml with jquery script.

```
$(function(){
    $("#foo").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();


        $.ajax({
            url: '/kontakt',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            data: ($("#foo").serialize()),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            }
        });
    })
})
```

Form has "foo" id;

The problem is, that when I submit I get respond like this each time: (its from console)

```
Object
-email :Object
-message :Object
-subject :Object
-personal-data :Object
```

and when I open for exmaple "message Object"
it shows me : isEmpty :" Field is required" even when the message field isn't empty!

Could anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what does the console.log display?

Comment: Hey I just solved it. 
I removed:
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   async: true,

and now console.log display: 
-email : Object
-personal-data : Object
-message : Object
-subject: Object 

And when I open for example email: Object I get 
- email : isEmpty("Field is required") //When the email input is empty

-email : invalidFormat("Thats not an email adres") when I try send email like blablabla 
So It seems that it works, at least for now. 

But why it didn't work with
"contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   async: true," 
?

Comment: async is true by default, so your problems is the content type , your php code doesn't recognize the data in json format it expects data as url encoded key value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` to send the data as url encoded